Evaluating binomial sum with $k^2$
I am currently trying to evaluate the sum
\begin{equation}
   \sum_{k = 0}^N \binom{N}{k}e^{c k^2}
\end{equation}
If it were $k^2 \to k$ this would readily give $\left(1+ e^{c}\right)^N$, but I was wondering if this slightly different sum would admit a simple expression as well, even in the large $N$ limit.

Here is a simple expression: $\approx e^{cN^2}$. Depending on your application this may be a good enough way to think about it.

There's no reason to expect an explicit sum. The function $e^{ck^2}$ grows very quickly and, as Sean says, that means the sum is dominated by its largest terms, which occur when $k \approx N$.
